# Using Laravel How can I make "current_page" and meta data appears in the end of my json file ( I want the file starts with {"data":[

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, pagination

**This is the data I get now:** (Ignore this) they asked me to write more details but there is nothing more to write actaully so I'm writing this text for no reason, sorry about that.

```
 {
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "created_at": "2022-07-20T00:00:00.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-20T00:00:00.000000Z",
    "status": 1,
    "order": 1,
    "gallery_id": 22,
    "gallery": {
    "id": 22,
    "name": "Test Fine Art",
    "description": null,
    "image": null,
    "exhibition_count": 5,
    "has_created_exhibition": 1,
    "stripe_id": null,
    "pm_type": null,
    "pm_last_four": null,
    "trial_ends_at": null,
    "created_at": "2022-07-20T15:25:02.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-20T15:25:03.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "free_rooms_plan_id": 0,
    "free_rooms": 0,
    "thumbnail": null,
    "owner": {
    "id": 187,
    "first_name": "Alina",
    "last_name": "test@gmail.com",
    "email": "testt@gmail.com",
    "email_verified_at": "2022-07-20T15:24:10.000000Z",
    "is_active": 1,
    "permission_level": 0,
    "provider": null,
    "provider_id": null,
    "access_token": null,
    "imported_user_id": 206,
    "created_at": "2022-07-20T15:24:10.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-20T15:24:10.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "permissions": {
    "gallery_id": 22,
    "user_id": 187,
    "user_type": "owner"
    }
    },
    "users": [
    {
    "id": 187,
    "first_name": "Alina",
    "last_name": "test@gmail.com",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "email_verified_at": "2022-07-20T15:24:10.000000Z",
    "is_active": 1,
    "permission_level": 0,
    "provider": null,
    "provider_id": null,
    "access_token": null,
    "imported_user_id": 206,
    "created_at": "2022-07-20T15:24:10.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-20T15:24:10.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "permissions": {
    "gallery_id": 22,
    "user_id": 187,
    "user_type": "owner"
    }
    }
    ]
    }
    }
    ],
    "first_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/lobby?page=1",
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "last_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/lobby?page=1",
    "links": [
    {
    "url": null,
    "label": "&laquo; Previous",
    "active": false
    },
    {
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/lobby?page=1",
    "label": "1",
    "active": true
    },
    {
    "url": null,
    "label": "Next &raquo;",
    "active": false
    }
    ],
    "next_page_url": null,
    "path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/lobby",
    "per_page": 10,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 1,
    "total": 1
    }
```

**I want "current_page" and other data in the bottom like this for examble:**

```
        {
    "data": [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "created_at": "2022-07-20T00:00:00.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-20T00:00:00.000000Z",
    "status": 1,
    "order": 1,
    "gallery_id": 22,
    "gallery": {
    "id": 22,
    "name": "Test Fine Art",
    "description": null,
    "image": null,
    "exhibition_count": 5,
    "has_created_exhibition": 1,
    "stripe_id": null,
    "pm_type": null,
    "pm_last_four": null,
    "trial_ends_at": null,
    "created_at": "2022-07-20T15:25:02.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-20T15:25:03.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "free_rooms_plan_id": 0,
    "free_rooms": 0,
    "thumbnail": null,
    "owner": {
    "id": 187,
    "first_name": "Alina",
    "last_name": "test@gmail.com",
    "email": "testt@gmail.com",
    "email_verified_at": "2022-07-20T15:24:10.000000Z",
    "is_active": 1,
    "permission_level": 0,
    "provider": null,
    "provider_id": null,
    "access_token": null,
    "imported_user_id": 206,
    "created_at": "2022-07-20T15:24:10.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-20T15:24:10.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "permissions": {
    "gallery_id": 22,
    "user_id": 187,
    "user_type": "owner"
    }
    },
    "users": [
    {
    "id": 187,
    "first_name": "Alina",
    "last_name": "test@gmail.com",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "email_verified_at": "2022-07-20T15:24:10.000000Z",
    "is_active": 1,
    "permission_level": 0,
    "provider": null,
    "provider_id": null,
    "access_token": null,
    "imported_user_id": 206,
    "created_at": "2022-07-20T15:24:10.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-07-20T15:24:10.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "permissions": {
    "gallery_id": 22,
    "user_id": 187,
    "user_type": "owner"
    }
    }
    ]
    }
    }
    ],
    "meta": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 3,
    "links": [
    {
    "url": null,
    "label": "&laquo; Previous",
    "active": false
    },
    {
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/room?page=1",
    "label": "1",
    "active": 

true
},
{
"url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/room?page=2",
"label": "2",
"active": false
},
{
"url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/room?page=3",
"label": "3",
"active": false
},
{
"url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/room?page=2",
"label": "Next &raquo;",
"active": false
}
],
"path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/room",
"per_page": 50,
"to": 50,
"total": 107
}
```

**This is the function which return the data in Laravel:**

```
public function avr_lobby(Request $request){
    return $lobbyRooms = LobbyRoom::orderBy('order','ASC')->with('gallery')->paginate(10);
}
```

Comment: Or if there is any other way to move "current_page" from the top

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own request(**php artisan make:request ...**). In which you need to select the fields that you need. This will automatically add the "data: [...]"